# Check if two numbers are both positive or both negative

Tags: javascript

I did not find a better name for this question...

I want to check if two numbers are either both smaller than 0, both 0 or both greater than 0.
Is there an easier way than this?

```
if (nr0 < 0 && nr1 < 0 || nr0 == 0 && nr1 == 0 || nr0 > 0 && nr1 > 0) {
    //do smth...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can multiply the numbers and check the multiplication should be positive (this will cover both being negative and both being positive) or they should be equal (which will cover the 0 case)

```
if(nr1*nr2 > 0 || (nr1 === nr2)){
    console.log("On the same side of number scale");
}
```

Comment: Depending on numbers this can cause integer overflow, so I wouldn't rely on that solution too much.

Comment: This does not work for very small numbers, e.g. `-1e-64 * -1e-1164 > 0` is `false`.

Answer (score 14):

For readability and simplicity I would suggest:

```
if (Math.sign(nr0) == Math.sign(nr1)) {
    //...
}
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign):

> If the argument is a positive number, negative number, positive zero or negative zero, [`Math.sign`] will return 1, -1, 0 or -0 respectively. Otherwise, NaN is returned.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be:

```
if ( nr0 * nr1 > 0 || (nr0 == 0 && nr1 == 0)) {
    // do sth...
}
```